# What is the MD5 of this code in Android?

Tags: android

```
string s1=textbox1.Text;
string s2="";
foreach(char c in s1)  {
    s2 = s2 + Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString();
 }

 UTF8Encoding ue = new UTF8Encoding();
 byte[] bytes = ue.GetBytes(s2);
 MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
 byte[] h1 = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);        
 textbox2.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BitCo  nverter.ToString(h1), "-", "").ToLower();
```

Comment: Remarkable to post a question without a single word. I assume the above is a code snippet in C# which you want to port to Java, but in that case please 1) describe what you want to do 2) do include code but please clean it up and remove stuff irrelevant to the question such as your text boxes etc and 3) Try googling or going to d.android.com, it should take you a few seconds to find the relevant crypto classes (hint java.security.MessageDigest)

Answer (score 0):

`MD5CryptoServiceProvider` is a class to encrypt the bytes using `MD5` encryption algorithm.  If you are asking 'MD5' variable, it is the instance of the`MD5CryptoServiceProvider` object.

http://www.encrypt.ro/cryptography/md5-message-digest-algorithm-5.html